# Incorrect Answer accepted as Correct

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

Observe [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71400/controlling-trigger-execution) question. I believe that the accepted answer leads people to the entirely wrong conclusion. Trigger flow can be controlled - it must be done manually. The answer accepted as correct states that it is not possible in the salesforce environment - which is just not true.

I am wondering how the site handles these types of things. Is there a process in place for a community review of the selected answers? Is there a reputation requirement on starting this process - which is why I can't find one?

Maybe I am incorrect in my interpretation of the answers/question and might be off base in thinking that this is worth correcting. To me the corrected answers seems to definitely stray people away from something that can be done in the system and I worry that someone will ready that first correct answer and assume that this is not possible.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I actually encountered a similar situation today. It wasn't accepted by it got a high amount of up-votes - which was unnerving. It was also one of the rare occasions where I thought it was __very__ necessary for a down-vote.

Comment: Just a note about why the author likely accepted the answer.  He did say that he planned on consolidating into a single trigger to fix this (which is essentially what your answer describes doing).  He was really asking if there is a way to control it immediately without heavy code changes.  To that end, I believe the accepted answer actually is more correct because the OP already knows it's possible.  Your answer mostly just explains how to correctly consolidate them.

Comment: I actually felt the need to give the accepted answer a thumbs up because it really directly answers the exact question OP asked.  If I had asked the question the way the OP did I would actually find the accepted answer more useful than yours.  That doesn't mean other users won't find what you said useful.  It just doesn't answer the question OP was asking.  Sorry for the length of response... hopefully it made sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a tough call. To be honest the accepted answer isn't exactly wrong, you can't control the order of trigger execution using standard platform functionality, but as you quite rightly state, you CAN do it manually.

One mechanism the site does have of course, is voting, and quite rightly you've received more votes (and so far more rep) than the author of the accepted answer. You could appear to the OP to change the accepted answer, but aside from that nothing can really be done (mods can't change it for instance).

I suspect over time your answer will continue to attract more votes, while the accepted one will not; it'll quickly become apparent (as it is already purely down to the length of the answers) as to which is the more informative of the two.

Comment: Agreed that the answer isn't exactly wrong. You can't control the order of separate triggers firing on the same object/dml operation, although the answer doesn't exactly say that.